# How to insert multiple queries with mysqli object oriented

Tags: mysqli

```
$db->query("UPDATE users SET solde = solde - '$aDeduire' WHERE telephone = '$msisdn'"); // works
$db->query("UPDATE users SET solde = solde + '$montant' WHERE telephone = '$numaPayer'"); //works
$db->query("UPDATE systems SET solde = solde + '$fraisTransaction' WHERE nom = 'SYSTEM'"); //works
$db->query("INSERT INTO transactions (day, description, expediteur, destinataire, debit, credit, numserie ) 

VALUES (NOW(), '$textExp', '$msisdn',null ,'$montant',null , '$numSerie')");// not working

$db->query("INSERT INTO transactions (day, description, expediteur, destinataire, debit, credit, numserie )

VALUES (NOW(), '$textDes't, null, '$numaPayer', null,'$montant', '$numSerie')"); // not working

$db->query("INSERT INTO transactions (day, description, expediteur, destinataire, debit, credit, numserie )

VALUES (NOW(), '$textSyst', null,'SYSTEM', null, '$montant', '$numSerie')");// not working
```

Please can anyone help with this code.
I'm trying to insert multiple dats at once.
what's wrong with the code?

Comment: What is the error message you got? Learn about prepared statemens. And add the ddl.

Comment: there is no error message.

Comment: just when I check the database nothing is inserted

Answer (score 0):

```
$db->query("INSERT INTO transactions (day, expediteur, destinataire, debit, credit, description, numserie) 
                VALUES (NOW(), '$msisdn','' ,'$montant', 0, '$textExp', '$numSerie'), 
                        (NOW(), '', '$numaPayer', 0,'$montant', '$textDest', '$numSerie'),
                        (NOW(), '$msisdn','', '$fraisTransaction', 0, '$textFrais', '$numSerie'), 
                        (NOW(), '','SYSTEM', 0, '$fraisTransaction', '$textSyst', '$numSerie')");
```

here is how I solved it

regards